# How to execute blocking calls within a Spring Webflux / Reactor Netty web application

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

In my use case where I have a Spring Webflux microservice with Reactor Netty, I have the following dependencies:

- `org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-starter-webflux` (2.0.1.RELEASE)
- `org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive` (2.0.1.RELEASE)
- `org.projectreactor.reactor-spring` (1.0.1.RELEASE)

For a very specific case I need to retrieve some information from my Mongo database, and process this into query parameters send with my reactive `WebClient`. As the `WebClient` nor the `UriComponentsBuilder` accepts a Publisher (Mono / Flux) I used a `#block()` call to receive the results.

Since `reactor-core` (version 0.7.6.RELEASE) which has been included in the latest `spring-boot-dependencies` (version 2.0.1.RELEASE) it is not possible anymore to use: `block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread xxx`, see -> https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/312

My code snippet:

```java
public Mono<FooBar> getFooBar(Foo foo) {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    parameters.add("size", foo.getSize());
    parameters.addAll("bars", barReactiveCrudRepository.findAllByIdentifierIn(foo.getBarIdentifiers()) // This obviously returns a Flux
        .map(Bar::toString)
        .collectList()
        .block());

    String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://base-url/")
        .port(8081)
        .path("/foo-bar")
        .queryParams(parameters)
        .build()
        .toString();

    return webClient.get()
        .uri(url)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(FooBar.class);
}
```

This worked with `spring-boot` version 2.0.0.RELEASE, but since the upgrade to version 2.0.1.RELEASE and hence the upgrade from `reactor-core` to version 0.7.6.RELEASE it is not allowed anymore.

The only real solution I see is to include a block (non-reactive) repository / mongo client as well, but I'm not sure if that is encouraged. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. We have very similar code that would have encountered some issues on our next upgrade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `WebClient` does not accept a `Publisher` type for its request URL, but nothing prevents you from doing the following:

```java
public Mono<FooBar> getFooBar(Foo foo) {

    Mono<List<String>> bars = barReactiveCrudRepository
        .findAllByIdentifierIn(foo.getBarIdentifiers())
        .map(Bar::toString)
        .collectList();

    Mono<FooBar> foobar = bars.flatMap(b -> {

        MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        parameters.add("size", foo.getSize());
        parameters.addAll("bars", b);

        String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://base-url/")
            .port(8081)
            .path("/foo-bar")
            .queryParams(parameters)
            .build()
            .toString();

        return webClient.get()
            .uri(url)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(FooBar.class);
    });
    return foobar;         
}
```

If anything, this new reactor-core inspection saved you from crashing your whole application with this blocking call in the middle of a WebFlux handler.

Comment: Is this not blocking, too?  If yes, probably some publishOn(Scheduler.elastic()) or similar would make sense, right? (I'm not an expert on this, though)

Comment: @Frischling Please point to the part that you think is blocking.

Comment: The whole webClient.get()... part. It's packed in a Mono, yes, but in the end data is transmitted, and can be arbitrarily slow; so if much data is transferred, and takes a lot of time, it should block the main thread, right?

Comment: Calling webClient.get() does not do anything with I/O. Subscribing to the Mono will start the whole thing. This reactive pipeline has no blocking I/O, so no thread will be blocked at any time. The remote might take a lot of time to answer (we can't solve latency for the whole world), but still it makes no difference: no blocking operation, no thread is blocked.

Comment: Thank you Brian! This seemed to do it, i'm still relatively new to reactive programming, and this was one scenario I coudn't tackle myself. Thanks for help and great example hopefully as well for others!

Comment: @BrianClozel, is it possible to handle errors inside as well? With things like `onStatus(is4xxError...)`?

Comment: @Urosh T. I don't understand; please ask a new question.