# Mongo Flux/Mono get object/s

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, project-reactor

I want get object/objects from Flux/Mono.
I use

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I do something like that:

```
    Mono<UserEntity> byEmail = userRepository.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail());
    UserEntity block = byEmail.block();
```

And I have error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3
```

Why? There is any different way to get object/objects?

How in reactive programming do something that:
In RequestBody you have UserDto.

Check the email exist in database if not create user.

### ANSWER UPDATE FROM @simon-baslé

```
 return userRepository.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail())
    //rethrow DB errors as BadRequestException, except user exists
    .onErrorResume(t -> Mono.error(new BadRequestException()))
    //throwing in map is converted to onError signal
    .map(ifItGoesThereItExist-> { throw new UserByEmailExistException(); })
    //switchIfEmpty to replace an empty source with a different Mono
    .switchIfEmpty(createUser(userDto))
    //at this point, map can only receive an onNext from the createUser
    .map(u -> new ResponseEntity(u, HttpStatus.CREATED))
    ;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746372/how-to-execute-blocking-calls-within-a-spring-webflux-reactor-netty-web-applic

Comment: So, I can't get object because I can't block? So how I can check the user exist in database and return exception user exist?

Comment: you should subscribe the Mono Publisher, if you are using reactive programming.

Comment: @GauravSrivastav not in this case, the Spring framework does the subscription

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have found an answer, but let me elaborate a bit on it.

**why you can't block**

The error message you get indicates that you try to revert to blocking behavior inside a specific `Thread` (or thread pool) that is not adapted to blocking. This is the thread used by Spring Webflux (and under the cover, Netty) to process **every incoming request in the application**. As a consequence, if you block it, you prevent your application from serving new requests at all.

**Your answer, and a few small improvements**

First off, the `map` could be simplified because `null` values are not allowed in a `Flux` or `Mono`. The Spring Data `ReactiveCrudRepository` will return an empty `Mono` if the value is not in DB, not to be confused with a `Mono` that emits `null`:

```
---( null )---|->
onNext(null), onComplete() // onNext(null) being forbidden
```

vs

```
---|->
onComplete()
```

Also, I think that with `onErrorResume` you intended to wrap DB errors except the "user exists" case? If so, the placement of this `onErrorResume` is wrong because it is similar to a `catch(Throwable e)` that will also catch the `UserByEmailExistException`. Put it *before* the `map`. You can also directly throw from within the map.

So this boils down to detecting an empty `Mono` vs valued `Mono`, replace the empty one by an asynchronous DB save and the valued one by an `onError`:

**TL;DR Gimme the code**

```java
return userRepository.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail())
        //rethrow DB errors as BadRequestException, except user exists
        .onErrorResume(t -> Mono.error(new BadRequestException()))
        //throwing in map is converted to onError signal
        .map(ifItGoesThereItExist-> { throw new UserByEmailExistException(); })
        //switchIfEmpty to replace an empty source with a different Mono
        .switchIfEmpty(createUser(userDto))
        //at this point, map can only receive an onNext from the createUser
        .map(u -> new ResponseEntity(u, HttpStatus.CREATED))
        ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I know more. I just started thinking reactively.

If I want check the `Mono` is empty so the map will not be called?