# Generate Flux<Result> from two Flux

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm working now with `Flux`. I want create one `Flux<Result>` from two different objects `Flux`. I know I have to use `BiFunction` but I don't know how. 
First object have PK and second FK to first object. I want zip that object which the PK=FK.

Description problem:
 I have a case at work where I have a list of houses and a list in which I was. I need to return the result with all the houses, I will only change the true / false flag on the Result object. The second list of course may have fewer elements.

Can anyone suggest something like that or any other way?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest

public class WholesaleControllerTest {

@Test
public void testZipFlux() {
    Flux<Flux1> flux1 = Flux.just(new Flux1(1, "test1"), new Flux1(2, "test2"), new Flux1(3, "test3"));
    flux1.subscribe(item -> System.out.println("Flux1 " + item));
    Flux<Flux2> flux2 = Flux.just(new Flux2(2, true), new Flux2(1, false), new Flux2(3, true));
    flux2.subscribe(item -> System.out.println("Flux2 " + item));


    Flux<Result> = ...//TODO zip flux1 and flux2 to RESULT

}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
class Flux1{
    private int id;
    private String value;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
class Flux2{
    private int id_fk_flux2;
    private boolean value;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
class Result{
    private int id;
    private String flux1Value;
    private boolean flux2Value;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you use `Flux.concat(flux1,flux2)` for these?

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc no for concat to work, types of both the flux to be same.@Deluxx, i am afraid you cannot use zipWith either, because, the order in both the flux are different. so when you encounter 1st item in flux1 and flux2 you cannot match

Comment: I did it especially. I have a case at work where I have a list of houses and a list in which I was. I need to return the result with all the houses, I will only change the true / false flag on the `Result` object. The second list of course may have fewer elements.
Is there any other way?

Comment: Could you please clarify guarantees that you need? What do you expect if fluxes dont have items with common pk?

Comment: I have two cases.
1. If not, set the specific value for example false
2. if not, not create new element to `Result`

Comment: Are the streams ordered by the key? In your example the second is not. That would make a reactive approach almost pointless because you need to buffer and sort the elements first.

Comment: Even if it does not sort the results, it does not solve the problem. When the list will not be equal.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do. But I have to say, this is not strictly reactive programming(because I am using block on first flux to create a map).

Having said that, I cannot think of any other way

```
Map<Integer, Flux1> flux1Map = flux1.collectMap(Flux1::getId, Function.identity()).block();

Flux<Result> results = flux2.flatMap(item -> {
        //TODO : Handle cases like key not found in flux1
        Flux1 entry = flux1Map.get(item.getId_fk_flux2());
        Result result = new Result(entry.getId(), entry.getValue(), item.isValue());
        return Mono.just(result);
    }).collectList().flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
```

Comment: I have problem with `block()` because I have error : `block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking. `

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746372/how-to-execute-blocking-calls-within-a-spring-webflux-reactor-netty-web-applic

Comment: But this is block resolution. I have to created that nonblocking :/

Comment: Given ur requirement .. I don't think it is possible. Let us know if you manage to do it.  Cheers